# Does awk always discard trailing characters when parsing a number?

Tags: awk

With `awk` I need to parse percentage numbers (with a trailing `%´) and check if they exceed a certain percentage.

Normal parsing simply ignores any trailing characters like:

```
% echo "99%" | awk '{print ($1 + 0)}'
99
```

except, of course, for strings consisting of `e` and number:

```
echo "99e4" | awk '{print ($1 + 0)}'                 
990000
```

Is this stable behavior and the same for different `awk`s or would it be advised to explicitly remove the `%`?

Comment: Your question has been answered correctly for the case you show where you're adding `0` to a string that contains a number but I notice you say `check if they exceed a certain percentage` so just to be clear - don't assume that same conversion will happen when comparing such input to a number, e.g. `echo '10%' | awk '$1 > 5'` would not output `10%`, you'd need to use `echo '10%' | awk '($1+0) > 5'` to force the conversion to a number manually before the comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is stable behaviour across AWK implementations. It is documented in [the GNU AWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html) as follows:

> A string is converted to a number by interpreting any numeric prefix of the string as numerals: `"2.5"` converts to 2.5, `"1e3"` converts to 1,000, and `"25fix"` has a numeric value of 25. Strings that can’t be interpreted as valid numbers convert to zero.

It is also documented, albeit more verbosely, [in the POSIX specification for `awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).